# What search algorithm is used in the game "Circle the Dot"?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I came across a game called "Circle the dot" on iOS and android that felt like it was intelligent. But I figured I can try making it.. I don't know where to start. Any idea on how they must have done it.. I'm thinking BFS ? Thanks in advance. (It's just for fun to gain experience im not going to publish it )

Comment: I'm thinking [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Comment: But i don't think it's weighted.

Comment: A* doesn't use weights, it uses heuristics which *could* be weights, but it could also be the closest distance to the destination.

Comment: But why do we need heuristic distance.. like you said distance is enough.. In that case you don't need A*, right ?

Comment: I think you are confused on the term heuristic. It is simply a cost function; a shorter distance costs less. Think of BFS as a "**B**rute **F**orce **S**olution" whereas A* will return an optimal solution with the correct heuristic.

Comment: Oh ok. How do you suggest I calculate the heuristic for a certain "dot". Any ideas ? Thanks for helping me out !

Comment: Thanks a lot I think I have an I idea to calculate heuristic.  Thanks, why don't you post your comments as an answer and I will select it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94814/discussion-between-bsathvik-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breadth-first search may work, but a better alternative is an [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) because you can define your own [heuristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_(computer_science)) such as the [Manhattan distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaxicabMetric.html) to a destination dot.

Additionally, A* gives you the flexibility to mess with your heuristic to achieve different results whereas BFS will always return the same result.

Comment: Wait I have a doubt.. There are multiple destinations.. To which do I calculate the heuristic ?